# Web API Application consumes endpoint, which needs periodic password changes - how to automate?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, web-applications, asp.net-web-api2

Our web application, WebAPI2, consumes an external endpoint.  The external endpoint requires periodic password changes, so we would like to automate it, with the passwordChange endpoint it also has.

To prevent this being a manual job, we'd like to automate this.  What would be the best way to accomplish this periodically from my own application web api?

So the 2 things I wonder about are:

- How can I trigger it?  (The requirement is every 90 days, but there's no reason why we couldn't do it more often.)
- Where best to store it?  config/Database/another

Thanks.

Comment: web.config should be read-only.  How else you persist the variable password depends entirely on the rest of your application.  How secure does the pwd need to be?  Plain text on db table ok?  txt file on a share with restricted permissions?   How you refresh is also completely arbitrary... maybe use curl with a scheduled task?  Refresh on every request?  On App startup?  When it fails with bad password?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a scheduled task on the server that runs ever 90 days, generates a new password and then simply encrypts that password and saves it to your database.

The WepApi then just needs a way of pulling the password from the database, decrypting it and using it when calling the external endpoint.

I wouldn't be modifying the web.config in this manner nor would i ever store passwords in a txt file.